# Scale IDs columns in Machine Learning?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm new to Machine Learning and I'm currently working on a dataset that has a lot of ids columns.

I have about ten columns with ids that represent categories for example: 1248885 for one district, 4929994 for another, etc. These are numerical variable but it’s only a reference...

My question is: should I do scale (normalise) these ids or it does not make sense because they are only ids? Or should I treat them as categorical variables?

I can not delete them because my dataset contains almost exclusively ids.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: this question is better suited for stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please mark as solved if your question has been answered

Answer (score 2):

These are categorical, so you would not normalize or standardize them. You only do that with numerical values. If there are too many IDs, it might not be wise to one hot encode them either. You have to ask if these IDs are relevant to your prediction problem, are they IDs that are features that are defining something in your dataset, etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes they are relevant to my prediction, that’s why I can’t drop them. Thanks you so much for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot normalize these, if they are categorical variables (they represent a one element of a predefined category), you should one-hot encode them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Autoencoder or PCA to get data IDs with reduced dimensions and  use them in model. If you have names for IDs (like IDs for some product) then you can also use TD-IDF or Word2Vec to reduce the dimensions.